# How to implement your own hints in android application

Tags: android

I have prepared list with about 200 words for my application.
There are only names of mountain peaks (Polish) like Rysy, Giewont, Ornak, etc.

I would like to get this names as hints while user is writing a name of a peak.

For example - after running my app, user wants to find a Giewont but he doesn't know how to write it, when he apply G, there are suggestions for him "Giewont", "Grzes" and more.
If he apply Gi, then second hint - "Grzes" is not seen anymore.

Is there a possibility to implement something like this dynamically?

Also is there an option to remove "Android keyboard hints" in app or is this possible only in Android Phone?

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/9574/android-autocompletetextview-example-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for this, it works as I wanted .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with AutoCompleteTextView.
AutoCompleteTextView receives an ArrayAdapter object for suggestions like this:

```
val hints = {the name of peaks}
val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String> (context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, hints)
autoCompleteTextView.threshold(/* an integer for the threshold */ 1)
autoCompleteTextView.adapter(adapter)
```